# Why doesn't compiz show the outline when I use the grid?

Tags: unity, compiz

When I drag windows, instead of getting an outline like I would on a clean install, I get nothing, so I don't know what function the plugin will use before releasing the mouse, other than what I guess it will do. Is there something known to cause this to happen, and what can I do to get back the outline?

(**NB:** I have the outline enabled in the plugin settings, so **please** do not ask me to enable it :D (lol)!)

EDIT:
Now I have reinstalled the compiz plugins cleanly and still noting :(. What can I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have upgraded to 11.10 and the problem is now gone. It appears to have been a localized problem with my Compiz installation.